# Rest response returned a pdf with random characters

Tags: java, rest, pdf

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/merge", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/pdf")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getPDF(@RequestBody DocRequest req) {

        try {
        ArrayList<String> urls =  pdf.getFileList(req);
        pdf.mergePdf(urls, req); // <-- this will generate a pdf called "untitled.pdf" on the server (outputstream)
        byte[] pdf = Files.readAllBytes(new File("untitled.pdf").toPath());

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();     
        headers.setContentLength(pdf.length);
        headers.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=untitled.pdf"); 
        headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(pdf ,headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //if above did not return a proper response, then request is bad.
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

If I open the untitled.pdf on the server it would look fine. But when I use swagger to download the pdf, I can see that the PDF contains random characters on the file.
        The content image were okay, but the text in the pdf seems like bunch of question marks and some random characters such as example below

```
"7SLHZLYLHKILMVYL`V\LSLJ[`V\YPU]LZ[TLU[VW[PVUZ!
     (YH[PVYLX\PYLTLU[VM!T\Z[ILTHPU[HPULK\ZPUNVULPU]LZ[TLU[VW[PVUMYVT,8(;VY(?(7YLTPLY=07MVYL]LY`VUL
    V\[ZPKLT\[\HSM\UKZLSLJ[LKUV[PUJS\KPUN[OL.06VY:[HISL=HS\L-\UK
;OLTH_PT\TU\TI"
```

Why or what is causing this??

**Update**

The error when I tried to open the pdf through reader pops up the following message:

```
Cannot extract the embedded font 'CMOHAC+Helvetica-Light'. Some characters may not display or print correctly.
```

Also when I open up the pdf through reader I see bunch of dots instead of those characters if I just clicked on the pdf to open.

Comment: kind of think it is related to encoding...

Comment: is there a way to test or try to resolve it using a different encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Content-type header to application/pdf